# Xamarin appshell - force the second tab (View) to be created right away

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using the new Xamarin Appshell.

In my AppShell.xaml file I have a section of code like this:

```
    <TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Menu" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainMenuPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Map" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MapPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="S.O.S" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SOSPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

The Menu page is shown right away...which is what I want.  But I need to make a instance of the MapPage view right away after the Menu page is created. (This MapPAge will not be shown yet to the user.)  So when anyone touches that Map tab that initial instance of the MapPage view will be shown.  I never want to make a new instance of the MapView.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the instance of the tab, remove the DataTemplate Selector.

```
<ShellContent>
   <views:YourMapsPage />
</ShellContent>
```

> In a Shell application, every ContentPage object in a ShellContent
>   object is created during application startup
>
> However, Shell also allows pages to be created on demand, in response
>   to navigation. This can be accomplished by using the DataTemplate
>   markup extension to convert each ContentPage into a DataTemplate, and
>   then setting the result as the ShellContent.ContentTemplate property
>   value:

[From Shell Tabs Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs)